# $S_1 ,S_2$ submanifolds of $\mathbb{T}^2$. Does there exists a translation $L$, such that $T(S_1)\pitchfork S_2$?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, transversality

Let $\mathbb{T}^2 = [0,1]^2/\sim$ be the torus, and $S_1,S_2 \subset \mathbb{T}^2$ are smooth $1$-manifolds such that $$S_i =\dot{\bigcup}_{j=1}^{n_i} C_{j}^{i}, $$
where each $C_j^{i}$ is a $1$-manifold diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Let $L_{\varepsilon,\delta}: \mathbb{T}^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2 $ be the smooth diffeomorphism
$$L_{\varepsilon,\delta}\left([x,y]\right) = [x+\varepsilon,y+\delta].$$

> **My Question:** Is it possible guarantee that there exists $(\varepsilon, \delta)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, such that $L_{\varepsilon,\delta}(S_1) \pitchfork S_2$?

I don't have any good idea on how to solve this problem, can anyone help me?

I tried to find a smart way to apply the transversality theorem but it led me to nowhere.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the intent of the problem, but if we take $S_1 = S_2$ to be the circle $\{[\ast, 0]\}$, then any translation $L_{\epsilon, \delta}$ maps $S_1$ to the circle $\{[\ast, \delta]\}$, so $S_1 \cap S_2 \neq \emptyset$ implies $\delta \in \Bbb Z$, but then $L_{\epsilon, \delta}$ maps $S_1$ to $S_1 = S_2$, so $S_1 \not\pitchfork S_2$.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your example. Because  ${[∗,0]}⋔{[∗,δ]}$ if $\delta \not\in \mathbb{Z}$, once ${[∗,0]}\cap{[∗,δ]} = ∅$. So the translation $L_{0,\delta}$ do the job.

Comment: I think there is a miscommunication due to notation. Let me be more explicit: Take $S_1 = S_2 := \{[x, 0] : 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$. Then, any map $L_{\epsilon, \delta}$ maps $S_1$ to the parallel circle $\{[x, \delta] : 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$. Then $L_{\epsilon, \delta}(S_1)$ intersects $S_2$ iff $\delta$ is an integer. (Strictly speaking here, we're viewing $\Bbb T^2 = \Bbb R^2 / \sim$ here in the usual way.)

Comment: If $L_{{0,\delta}} (S_1)$ doesn't intersect $S_2$ then we get $L_{0,\delta} (S_1) ⋔ S_2$. Am I correct?

Comment: Usually $\pitchfork$ means "intersects transversely". Are you counting empty intersections as transverse intersections here?

Comment: In that case, I expect that not only is the assertion true, but that the set of $(\epsilon, \delta)$ which transversality doesn't hold has measure zero.

Comment: I learned (the definition that I'm using)  $A⋔B $ means that $A, B \subset M$ and for every $p \in A \cap B$, imply $T_p A + T_p B = T_p M$. But your last commentary, makes me realize how to solve the problem. If you post your commentary (saying that is a hint) I accept as an answer.

Comment: I'm glad you found the comment helpful as hint. I suggest instead that you write up your own solution as an answer, since that will probably be more helpful to any future readers.

Comment: Ok. I will do this tomorow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the records, the definitions that I'm using:

> **Definition 1:** Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds, $S \subset N$ a smooth submanifold and $f: M \to N$ a smooth funtion. Then $f \pitchfork S$ if for every $p$ $\in$ $M$ occurs one of the following conditions:
>
> - $f(p) \not \in S$
> - $f(p) \in S$ and $\text{d}f_p (T_{p}M) + T_{f(p)}S = T_p N. $
>
> **Definition 2:** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $S_1, S_2 \subset M$ smooth submanifolds. Then $S_1 \pitchfork S_2$ if for every $p$ $\in$ $S_1 \cap S_2$ follows $T_p S_1 + T_p S_2 = T_p M$.

Besides that, there exists the following well-known theorem

> **Theorem:** Let $M, N, S$ be smooth manifolds, and $F: M\times N \to S$ a smooth function such that $F \pitchfork Z$, where $Z$ is a smooth submanifold of $S$. Then  $\{p \in N;$ $F(\cdot,p) \pitchfork S\}$ is a residual set.

The above theorem also holds if we change word "residual" to "full measure set" (complementary of a null set).

The demonstration follows immediately from the fact that the function

$$F: S_1 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2 $$
$$([p],\varepsilon,\delta)\mapsto [p + (\varepsilon,\delta)] $$

satisfies $F \pitchfork S_2$, because $\text{d}F_q$ is obviously surjective. Then follows from Theorem 1 that the set $\{(\varepsilon,\delta) \in \mathbb{R}^2;$ $F(\cdot,\varepsilon,\delta) \pitchfork S_2\}$ isn't empty.